# How to clone a group (with permissions) in VSO?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have projects from two separate TFS collections that I am migrating to VSO. For this reason, I need two developer groups.

Is it possible to clone a group, with all permissions intact (even inherited ones)?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no clone functionality in the UI or a command line. The closest would probably be to write a script that used [tfssecurity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252504.aspx) to get the membership and permissions for a group and recreate it. There may be additional issues, but it will get you close at least.